# MPI C++ | How do I make the processes wait for the master?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I have a program to make that should do the following: Read the size of an array, read each element of the array, and then a number that I want to find in that array. The program must split the search for each process. The problem I have is that I do not know how to make all the slave processes wait for the master to finish the reading process. Here is what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

void searchForElementInArray(int left, int right, int myArray[], int number);
void readArrayAndNumber(int myArray[], int &arraySize, int &number);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int LIMIT = 100;
    int numberOfProcesses;
    int processRank;
    int error;
    int length;

    int myArray[1010];
    int arraySize;
    int number;

    error = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    if (error != MPI_SUCCESS) {
        cout << "Error starting MPI program. Terminating.\n";
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, error);
    }

    // get the number of processes
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numberOfProcesses);
    MPI_Bcast(&arraySize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // Length of each interval
    length = arraySize / numberOfProcesses;

    //get the process rank
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processRank);

    if (!processRank) { // Master

        readArrayAndNumber(myArray, arraySize, number);

        MPI_Send(&myArray, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&arraySize, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
    else { // Slave

        if (processRank != numberOfProcesses - 1) {

            MPI_Recv(&myArray, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&arraySize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);


            searchForElementInArray(length * processRank, length * processRank + length, myArray, 66);

            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        }
        else {


            MPI_Recv(&myArray, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&arraySize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);


            searchForElementInArray(length * processRank, arraySize, myArray, 66);

            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        }

    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void searchForElementInArray(int left, int right, int myArray[], int number) {

    int flag = 0;

    cout << "Searched positions: ";

    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {

        cout << i << " ";
        if (myArray[i] == number) {

            cout << endl << "Found on position " << i;
            flag = 1;
            break;

        }


    }

    if (flag == 0) {

        cout << endl << "Not found";

    }

    int processRank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &processRank);
    cout << " by Process: " << processRank << endl << endl;

}

void readArrayAndNumber(int myArray[], int &arraySize, int &number) {

    cin >> arraySize;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {

        cin >> myArray[i];

    }
    cin >> number;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - please see "How to ask questions" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should not put 'MPI_Barrier` inside if-block if not all processes can enter because that function needs to be called by all processes. Instead of multiple `MPI_Barrier` in each if-block, just put one where ever you want all processes to stop by and wait for others.

Comment: So in my case where would be best to place MPI_Barrier to make them wait for each other ? I need to do the reading part and then the search part done by each of the remaining processes.